# debugging dependency property changes wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to debug why or who is setting a dependency property in a wpf project.
Are there any techniques to figure out and debug dependency property changed events?

I am setting a breakpoint in OnProertyChanged event handler, but the problem is ... the call stack shows:

OnPropertyChanged

[External Code]

```
myProgram.exe!EntryPoint.EntryPointRunner.Execute() Line 105 + 0x10 bytes   C#
```

I also tried setting a break point in SetValue() call hoping that I would be able to see the call stack there but...that is not being called at all which was weird unless setting the property in xaml would not call the SetValue().

Any suggestions are really appreciated thanks,

Comment: I don't know if this will give you the information you need, but in Visual Studio, in the Options (Tool menu), under Debugging -> Output Window, there are a bunch of options related to logging WPF Data Binding, Dependency Properties, etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I put a breakpoint on WPF DependencyProperty retrieval?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57417683/how-can-i-put-a-breakpoint-on-wpf-dependencyproperty-retrieval)

Answer (score 0):

If your property is changed via binding, the break point in `SetValue` will not hit.

Right click the call stack and check the option `Show External Code` This way you can see which .Net method changed your property.