# How can I put a breakpoint on WPF DependencyProperty retrieval?

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties

How can I create a breakpoint triggered when when WPF is ***retrieving*** the value of my custom DependencyProperty?

[I wrote this question poorly the first time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57417213/why-is-my-breakpoint-on-wpf-dependencyproperty-retrieval-not-being-hit?noredirect=1#comment101314274_57417213).   Unfortunately, understanding [why my breakpoint is not hit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/xaml-loading-and-dependency-properties) doesn't solve my real problem.  This is the question I should have asked.  Searching high and low I still can't see how to do this.

If WPF is going to bypass my getter function, is there some other way?

I need this for debugging purposes, to examine the state of my control live in the debugger at the exact moment WPF retrieves this property.

To refresh, below is my custom dependency property

```
private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey ColorizerPropertyKey =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly(
        nameof(Colorizer),
        typeof(SurfaceSeries3DColorizer),
        typeof(SurfaceDisplay),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata());

private static readonly DependencyProperty ColorizerProperty = 
    ColorizerPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;

public SurfaceSeries3DColorizer Colorizer
{
    get => (SurfaceSeries3DColorizer) GetValue(ColorizerProperty);
    private set => SetValue(ColorizerPropertyKey, value);
}
```

...and this is the XAML that binds to it

```
<tk:SurfaceSeries3D ItemsSource="{Binding Points}"
                    XValueBinding="X"
                    YValueBinding="Y"
                    ZValueBinding="Z"
                    Colorizer="{Binding Colorizer}"
                    />
```

Comment: WPF calls GetValue. That's not inside your code. No way to put a breakpoint anywhere.

Comment: I understand how it works.  I'm looking for a way around it.  I already have one for when WPF *sets* my value, I can just specify a value-changed callback in the metadata and put a breakpoint there.  I'm looking for some getter equivalent or other work-around

Comment: You should also understand that you are asking for the impossible.

Comment: Well I've already asked it so maybe someone else out there has figured out a way, eh?

Comment: I think the only alternative would be to create a dummy converter and apply it to the binding. By dummy converter, I mean a IValueConverter that just returns whatever was passed in. Then, when WPF gets the value of the DP, it'll pass it over to the converter. Not exactly what you said you wanted but perhaps it'll help? Add a unique converter parameter if you have more than one binding so you know which one you're dealing with. Colorize="{Binding Colorizer, Converter={StaticResource DummyConverter}, ConverterParameter=Instance1}".

Comment: I really like this idea.  However as far as I can reason, it would not help me.  Yes, I would, in the converter, have the value of the property being retrieved.  But I would not have any reference to the control from which it was being retrieved and that is the thing I want to examine in the debugger.  Still a dummy converter seems like a good approach for debugging a number of other situations not too different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way for that, but you have to keep in mind that your debuggee (the application you debug) and the debugger itself will become very unresponsive.

So if you're trying to diagnose some nasty and rare occurring bug, this might help. Otherwise, it is pretty useless, because your app will be almost unusable.

Go to the **Breakpoints** window in Visual Studio and choose **New** --> **Function Breakpoint...**.

Type in:

```
System.Windows.DependencyObject.GetValue
```

Enable the **Condition** checkbox and enter your condition:

```
dp == YourNamespace.YourClass.YourDependencyProperty
```

Here, `dp` is the `GetValue` method's argument name (don't change) and `YourNamespace.YourClass.YourDependencyProperty` is the full name of your dependency property `public` field (change).

Now, hit F5 and enjoy.

Behind the scenes, the debugger will check **each and every** call to the `System.Windows.DependencyObject.GetValue` method, and when the provided argument will be your property, the debugger will break your app.

Note that WPF calls that method **very frequently** - that's why your app and the debugger will become unresponsive: a condition will be checked on each call, and that condition requires data transfer between debugger and debuggee.